# How is the URL "ai." parsed?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, url

I found that browsing http://ai. returns a web page.

> This is no longer a public website. If you have come here you are at
> the wrong place. You probably want to go to one of these sites:
>
> ```
> whois.nic.ai To do "whois" lookups.
> auction.whois.ai Auction site for expired .ai domains.
> whois.ai/faq.html General FAQ for .ai domains.
> whois.ai/eppfaq.html FAQ for .ai registrars.
> zenaida.cate.ai if you used to login here years ago
> ```

This looks like a `.ai` domain, but it is not `xxx.ai.`, nor is it `.ai.`, but simply `ai.`, and it seems an invalid URL.

How is this URL parsed and DNS resolved? And is this satisfy the specification? (Maybe RFC?)

For example, I looked for the same example with other domain names, but they did not work (`com.`, `net.`).

Comment: The URL has a protocol component and a path component. Why do you think it's invalid?

Comment: DNS is resolved exactly as usual. See `dig any ai.` or `dig any uk.` or even `dig any com.` I don't see the problem here

Comment: The fact that it's not *common* to use naked TLD's doesn't make them invalid.

Comment: @ChrisDavies In the RFC 952, hostname is defined as `<official hostname> ::= <hname>,  <hname> ::= <name>*["."<name>], <name>  ::= <let>[*[<let-or-digit-or-hyphen>]<let-or-digit>]` . My understanding is that this definition states that hostname necessary consist of one or more letter. And `ai.` doesn't have hostname, so I consider `ai.` is invalid.

Comment: I may have been mistaken. Does this definition define that even ``(just an empty string) is a valid hostname not only `.ai` ? (`<hname> ::= <name>*["."<name>]` allow empty string maybe)

Comment: What type of question is that? this is a normal parsing - just someone has put an IN A on ai. See, the TLD is ".", under that all is zones. Basic DNS. Read up on the DNS RFC's.

Comment: RFC 952 is the obsolete DOD "hosts" file. You should be reading RFCs 1034 and 1035 for DNS, where it's quite clear that `ai.` is a valid name

Answer (score 0):

Just using a dns record

```
    .           84489   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           84489   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4) in 71 ms

ai.         172800  IN  NS  a.lactld.org.
ai.         172800  IN  NS  pch.whois.ai.
ai.         172800  IN  NS  anycastdns1-cz.nic.ai.
ai.         172800  IN  NS  anycastdns2-cz.nic.ai.
;; Received 280 bytes from 192.58.128.30#53(192.58.128.30) in 248 ms

ai.         3600    IN  A   209.59.119.34
ai.         3600    IN  NS  a.lactld.org.
ai.         3600    IN  NS  pch.whois.ai.
ai.         3600    IN  NS  anycastdns1-cz.nic.ai.
ai.         3600    IN  NS  anycastdns2-cz.nic.ai.
;; Received 252 bytes from 200.0.68.10#53(200.0.68.10) in 133 ms
```

`dig +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats +trace ai. @8.8.4.4`